# Configure key to turn off mouse reporting in iTerm2

Tags: terminal, mouse, copy-paste, iterm2

Currently, mouse reporting is disabled using the `option` key. Is there a way to configure this to `shift` key i.e. I hold down `shift` to select text instead of `option`. I don't want to permanently remap the keys so it'd be better if I can configure just this action. I did not find any solution online.